# Restore Home Folders

Tags: windows-7

I accidently deleted my home folders. Those are:

- C:\Users\myname\Downloads
- C:\Users\myname\Dokumente
- C:\Users\myname\Bilder
- C:\Users\myname\Videos
- C:\Users\myname\Musik

**How can I restore them?** I do not want to restore the default location! Just the folder. The folders **should have an option pane to relocate that folder afterwards**.

**Clarification**:

- I am using Windows 7 Professional 64bit.
- I do not want the content back. In fact: There is no content in there yet.
- I don't use windows 7 libraries (what has this to do with the topic?)

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by restore. Do you need the contents back? Are you using Windows Vista/7 style Libraries?

Comment: How on earth did you delete protected windows folders?

Comment: Does it matter? - No!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now.

1. **MAKE BACKUPS!**
2. Create folders and call them "Pictures", "Downloads", "Videos", "Music", "Personal" and "Documents"
3. Don't wonder why "Personal" and "Documents".
4. Restart computer
5. The folders should be working again with the option pane to relocate them.
6. Adressing 2.: I don't know anymore if it was "Personal" or "Documents". Just create both and look which one is working after rebooting.
7. Enjoy!

I hope this helps someone having the same problem as I had.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click -> New Folder -> Name as you please.